# How to stop leaflet map to overlap other elements

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a leaflet map that is overlapping other elements on scroll, so what is leaflet default high z-index or is there any other way to keep it contained( My css skills are not that good)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do with z-index. The leaflet container needs to have a lower z-index, than the other elements.

Comment: Thanks, I found a list a z-indexes of elements of layers they provide on their maps in their documentation